# MS SQL Server check existence of registered Assembly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, .net-assembly

In a database I generally use a XML based version of a split function. Later on with some research I created a Assembly CLR version of the split function.

In a database update process (patch) I remove all user functions, patch the database and then create the user functions again. Due the patch process it will restore the XML version of the split function again.

I checked MSDN so far, but I wasn't able to find any hint for:
How can I check if a DLL is registered as an assembly inside the database?

In Management Studio I can open the database -> Program ability -> Assembly and can see the DLL, if it is registered. But I want to do this programmatically and use the CLR version on CREATE FUNCTION if the DLL is available, else I want to use the XML version to make sure that the split function is available in any case.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. There are more `sys.%assembly%` views, check them out, too.

```
select 
    *
from sys.assembly_files f
full outer join  sys.assemblies a
    on f.assembly_id=a.assembly_id
full outer join  sys.assembly_modules m
    on a.assembly_id=m.assembly_id
```